# Logic on updating FlatList in real-time after actions on children

Tags: reactjs, react-native, real-time, subscription, react-native-flatlist

I am wondering what would be the best way to update a `FlatList` when actions are being conducted on its children.

**Problem I am facing**

[image]

**What I am trying to do**

I am trying to find the most efficient way to update the counts of the number of comments and the number of likes on each `PostCard` (displayed by the `FlatList`) in real-time. When a comment is added through the `PostDetails` page of any post, the higher `FlatList` should refresh the count.

**My concerns/issues**

- I am aware of the `extraData` prop in `FlatList` for refreshing it, but I could not find a good way of using it, as my changes happen at a different/more granular level in the app.
- I thought about attaching queries and subscriptions on my `PostCard` component itself, and solely for updating the number of comments and likes, but I am worried about the performance consequences of having 100 FlatList elements that each have subscriptions to self-update.

I am assuming that my problem is, in a way, similar to updating a higher-level list of group chats for each user of a chat app, when messages are posted in any of these chats.

Comment: If the count is being displayed in each Flatlist item then you'd have to use extraData to re-render the Flatlist right?

Comment: @MattJameson That were my initial thoughts too, but the problem is that my ``Posts`` component (the one that manages the FlatList) doesn't "know" about the changes made to the children. I wouldn't even know what data to pass to ``extraData`` to make the list self-update.

Comment: Ok so maybe use Redux to save the changes made in the child components and then use the new state to re-render the Flatlist?